# error:Compatible type:java.util.String cannot be converted to String

Tags: java, string

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class String{ 

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a String: ");
        String s=in.nextLine();
    }    
}
```

Here's my code.
Whenever i compile this java code i get an error as:

> Incompatible types:java.util.String cannot be converted to String

```
String s=in.nextLine();
                ^
```

can any one tell me what should i do to get over it.

Comment: At which line??

Comment: __Do not__ name your class `String`.

Comment: Don't define a class named String. String is already a standard class used basically everywhere. You don't want such a name clash. And when you post an error, post the real one. There is no such thing as java.util.String. Unless you also chose to create your classes in the standard java.util package. Don't do that either.

Comment: thank you i just didn't noticed it

Answer (score 4):

You should not use names for your classes that are already used in JRE in package `java.lang.*`

Answer (score 1):

It happens because your class is named the same like the Java's `String` from `java.lang.*`, that is used basically everywhere.

Rename you class or use of prefixes like `com.app.myclass.String`.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Java packages avoids `class` name collisions**, so you need to use full class name prefixing with the package name (like **option1** below), whenever there is a conflict between multiple classes.
So to resolve your issue, you can pick one of the following:

(1)  `java.util.String s=in.nextLine();`

(2)  Change your class name `MyString`

You look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html) on how to avoid class name conflicts.